# Stop Windows 10 swapping drivers

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have an Intel network card that doesn't like the MS drivers. This is a common problem with this particular card apparently. The solution is to download the Intel drivers and install them. That works a treat but Windows switches back to the MS driver after a full shutdown/reboot and then the card won't work. It doesn't do it for a restart/sleep/hibernate. After a cold reboot I can uninstall the network card in device manager and the detect new hardware and it will switch to the Intel driver and start working. Is there a way to lock this device to a particular driver? Or a way to uninstall the built in MS driver? All I can find on google is how to stop windows update installing new drivers, but this isn't windows update. As the offending driver is part of windows I presume I can't delete it and if I did I presume it would come back.

The card is Intel 82579LM
Windows version is Windows 10 22H2

Edit: To the person who marked this a duplicate and closed my question, you are completely wrong. That other question is talking about something different and is NOT an answer to my question in any way at all. I have followed everything in that thread and many many other similar threads and it hasn't helped. That question is talking about windows update installing new drivers, my question relates to the basic process of windows automatically installing existing drivers during a cold boot. I did specify this is the my original question. Please open my question again.

Edit2: The very first line of the other question makes it very clear it's NOT a duplicate. "Every time Windows 10 runs updates". My problem is NOT happening when windows update is run, it is happening during a cold boot. This is very clearly specified in my original question. Please reopen my question.

Edit3: Hello? Is anyone actually reviewing this question? The suggested duplicate is simply wrong, this is quite simply NOT a duplicate of that other question and that other question does not answer my question in any way at all. Is someone looking at this? It's been 11 days. 11 days to ask a simple question.

Comment: Have you seen TenForums on preventing changes to specific drivers: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/146562-prevent-windows-update-updating-specific-device-driver.html and on stopping auto driver installation, https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/15989-turn-off-device-driver-automatic-installation-windows-10-a.html ? Also, are you installing the Intel driver as Admin (though I don't see how one could, otherwise)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I followed that exact tutorial and it had no impact. I think this is an example of stopping windows update from downloading new drivers but it doesn't stop windows doing it after a cold boot. Both drivers are available on windows so it's not a matter of windows update downloading new drivers.

Comment: For the person who marked this a duplicate, that question is a good example of exactly what I don't want. That question is referring to windows update downloading new drivers. I'm talking about the basic process of automatic driver install which has nothing to do with windows update. I did specify this in my original question

Comment: You may believe it is not the same, but reading what you have written it SOUNDS like exactly the same question. Merely saying it is different tells us nothing. This is one reason why we need to know EVERYTHING that you have tried, both to know what not suggest, and to know what is not a duplicate. Use the EDIT button to tell us all you've tried, clearly and explicitly.

Comment: @music2myear it's very simple. The question that is claimed to be a duplicate is about WINDOWS UPDATE. My question relates to PLUG AND PLAY. I don't need a windows update to go through for the problem to occur, I just need a cold boot. It's very different and I have mentioned that several times.

Comment: It's right there in the very first sentence of that other question "Every time Windows 10 runs updates", my issue is NOT to do with windows running updates. This was made very clear in my post. It's an issue when I do a cold boot. In fact I can run windows updates, even do a reboot of the computer, and my problem does not occur. My problem ONLY occurs when I do a cold boot. Both drivers exist on the machine and windows does not need to do an update for the problem to occur. Not sure how else I can say this.

Comment: OK, question was marked a duplicate within minutes of being put up, then 16 days later finally reversed. Now the question has dropped into oblivion so no replies. Not that I need one now but just came here out of morbid curiosity.